# Binary Serialization Reloading DLL Classes

Tags: c#, serialization, dll

I'm trying to make a board game framework that loads in each game as their own plugin classes (through dependency injection).  Each 'game' would then be it's own DLL.  Thus the plugin handles loading in the correct resource for a 'pawn' in a game, the proper image for the game board, any special logic the game needs, etc.

My proposed folder structure is

```
game.exe
plugins/
    /plugin1
        /textures
        plugin1.dll

    /plugin2
        /textures
        plugin2.dll
```

When you start a game, I have you use a filemanager to load the proper dll (will be refined in the future), and as other clients connect to you, it makes them load the plugin on their side too, or fail to connect if you don't also have a dll for that game.

An example of the code for loading is below:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(openPlugin.FileName);

string fullTypeName = "TestPlugin.TestPlugin";
Type dllType = assembly.GetType(fullTypeName);
IPlugin myType = (IPlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(dllType);
```

I'm using the hard coded string for the type name for now, but that will eventually change.

To play with other people, there is a network architecture that primarily consists of using binary serialization of objects.  The problem is when I unserialize an object of a class that was in a plugin dll, the system wants to reload the dll from file. When it trys to reload it, it follows normal rules and looks for the dll in the directory of the exe (This all works if I move the plugin dll to the main directory).

Here is a sample of the binary serialization if it helps

```
public Stream SerializeObject(object obj)
{
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream();

    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);

    return stream;
}

/// <summary>
/// Deserializes Objects
/// </summary>
/// <param name="stream">Stream containing the binary objects</param>
public T DeserializeObject<T>(byte[] data)
{
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
    IRemotingFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

I wish I could make it less open ended, but what can I do to solve this and keep the directory structure I want?
- Make some form of custom loader to search recursively through plugins/ ?
- Choose a different method for binary serialization?
- When I 'load', am I not doing it properly for the class is loaded into 'memory' for future uses?

I'm welcome to architectural changes if you read this and go 'why the heck is he doing it that way??' :)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Use `Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("dllPath");` instead of `Assembly.LoadFile()`

2) As your plugins have different names, you can put them into one directory and define the path in app.config to this dir.

3)It's probably good idea to load Dlls in other than main AppDomain so you can unload them without to restart your application, see my example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663068/how-to-find-dll-files-containing-nunit-tests/)

Comment: Is there -anyway- to do a recursive search for dll's?  Or what about the root cause of the serialization re-loading dll's I've already loaded?

Comment: @will step 2) should help you by searching, not sure about recursive